# React-native form not typing in TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Giving the components below, I am unable to type in `TextInput` the letter is written and then deleted, it seems a problem with updating the state. Any clue?

```
class myContainerComponent extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }
  onChange(value) {
    this.setState({
      value
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <PresentationalComponent 
        onChange={this.onChange}
        value={this.state.value}
      />
    )
  }    
}    
class PresentationalComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <TextInput 
        onChangeText={this.props.onChange}
        value={this.props.value}
      />
    )
  }

}
```

Any clue?

Comment: What returns onChangeText ? event or input value? type a console.log(value) in myContainerComponent => onChange

Comment: As you can read on the docs it returns the value you're inputting: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

Comment: I think you need to initialize value to empty string in constructor state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe both other answers are correct but you could simplify your code even more and get rid of the constructor declaration using an arrow function:

```
class myContainerComponent extends Component {

    state = {
        value: ''
    }

    onChange = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <PresentationalComponent
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={this.state.value}
            />
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should initialise your state in your constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: ''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your **myContainerComponent** constructor:

```
this.state = {
  value: '',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: {}
    };
   this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
 }

 onChange(value) {
   this.setState({
    value
 })
}

render() {
  return (
    <PresentationalComponent 
      onChange={this.onChange}
    value={this.state.value}
  />
)
}
}

class PresentationalComponent extends React.Component {

render() {
return(
  <TextInput 
    onChangeText={this.props.onChange}
    value={this.props.value}
  />
)}
}
```